# Compile Qt project from command line using msvc2017 in Windows

Tags: qt, qmake

I have a sample QtCreator project already configured to compile in release using Qt 5.9.2 msvc 2017 64 bit toolchain. I can compile it without any problem using QtCreator (and run the executable). But, I'm trying to learn how to compile it from commandline. That's what QtCreator seems to perform when it builds the project (I'll highlight commands that I suppose I need to execute manually):

> 17:19:47: Running steps for project Prueba...
>
> 17:19:47: Starting: **"C:\Qt\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\bin\qmake.exe" H:\home\alberto\Proyectos\ProyectoPrueba\Prueba\Prueba.pro -spec win32-msvc**
>
> Info: creating stash file H:\home\alberto\Proyectos\ProyectoPrueba\build.qmake.stash
>
> 17:19:47: The process "C:\Qt\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
>
> 17:19:47: Starting: **"C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" qmake_all**
>
> jom 1.1.2 - empower your cores
>
> 17:19:47: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
>
> 17:19:47: Starting: "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe"
>
> **C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release**
>
> cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -Zc:referenceBinding -O2 -MD -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -EHsc -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I..\Prueba -I. -IC:\Qt\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include -IC:\Qt\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore -Irelease -IC:\Qt\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Forelease\ @H:\home\alberto\AppData\Local\Temp\main.obj.9744.0.jom
>   main.cpp
>       link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:release\Prueba.exe @H:\home\alberto\AppData\Local\Temp\Prueba.exe.9744.905.jom
>
> 17:19:48: The process "C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited normally.
>   17:19:48: Elapsed time: 00:01.

That way, my first step is trying to execute qmake executable from the build directory, given that the build dir is empty. But, I got the following:

```
H:\home\alberto\Proyectos\ProyectoPrueba\build>"C:\Qt\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\bin\qmake.exe" H:\home\alberto\Proyectos\ProyectoPrueba\Prueba\Prueba.pro -spec win32-msvc
```

> Project ERROR: Cannot run compiler 'cl'. Maybe you forgot to setup the environment?

So, I have no clue of what's missing here. I also checked the original Makefile generated by Qt creator. At the top of the file, in some comments:

> Makefile for building: Prueba
>
> Generated by qmake (3.1) (Qt 5.9.2)
>
> Project:  ..\Prueba\Prueba.pro
>
> Template: app
>
> Command: C:\Qt\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile ..\Prueba\Prueba.pro -spec win32-msvc

So the command and also the current working dir seems to be good (the only difference is the relative path to .pro file instead of absolute path); I also used the relative path to the .pro file obtaining the same results.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Qt Creator and not even with Qt but with Microsoft C++ compiler which cannot run without providing its environment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt.aspx

Comment: thank you, @AlexanderVX. I tried to run all highlighted commands after executing vcvarsall.bat  and it worked, and a valid executable was generated.